# Interactive map in Html5

Tags: html, flash, geoserver

Right now, I'm using .swf Flash file in my web site to represent an interactive map. The map contains a couple of WMS layers rendered by Geoserver. I would like to use Html5 instead of flash. So what would be the best approch to create an interactive map that contains some Geoserver layers via Html5?

Comment: See if this helps you find a solution: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119143/how-can-i-add-google-map-layer-as-additional-layer-openlayer-osm

Answer (score 0):

There's a few javascript frameworks out there right now for consuming WMS layers as well as other formats.

[Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) and [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) are two popular ones.